# in flutter, Need to use 'Login()' in my main.dart file. Check my dart code below:

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

Here's the snippet of little bit of the code

```
class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  final double screenHeight, screenWidth;

  const Login({Key key, this.screenHeight, this.screenWidth}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginState createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  var _formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: PopBlue,
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          CustomPaint(
            painter: MyCustomPainter(),
            child: Container(
              height: widget.screenHeight * 0.65,
            ),
          ),
...
```

**Login** class is in **1st** line.
  i have to use this **Login** class as `home: Login()` in my **`main.dart`** file.
  i am not able to use this login class in my main code which is at main.dart file
help me finding a way to use this class in my `main.dart` file.

Comment: can you please show your main.dart file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've played around a bit and come up with this which should help get you started, (tested and working on Chrome)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(home: Login());
}

class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginState createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  var _formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue, //PopBlue,
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.65, //widget.screenHeight * 0.65,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.65,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
          CustomPaint(
            size: Size(300, 300),
            painter: MyCustomPainter(),
            // child: Container(
            //   height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.65,     //widget.screenHeight * 0.65,
            //   width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.65,
            //   color: Colors.red,                // ),             ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyCustomPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final left = 50.0;
    final top = 100.0;
    final right = 250.0;
    final bottom = 200.0;
    final rect = Rect.fromLTRB(left, top, right, bottom);
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 4;
    canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter old) => false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main.dart will be something like below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'path-of-your-login-page';//import './login.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Login();
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: screen is again blank

Comment: you will have to share your main.dart snippet in question and output of your screen

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean by "i am not able to use this login class in my main code"?

Is the IDE reporting a problem? If so, what does it say?

Or is it failing at run time? If so, what is the error message?

Comment: Well, what do you expect to see? i.e. what is in the CustomPainter? You really have to post your code if you want us to be able to figure out why it isn't working.